# sql, product inventory module

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have been tasked with creating a product inventory module.  After reading all the posts I can find on Stack Overflow, I have decided the best way is to not keep a separate, running ‘balance’, but to create one on the fly.  I have attached a representation of the tables involved.

Actually, it seems like I don't have enough reputation points to include a picture, so here is a link to a [dropbox file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wa0ky6jkl82t05a/ProductInventoryTransactionTables.jpg?dl=0):

So I have two questions, which are somewhat related, so it seem like I should include them in the same question posting, though I am not a frequent poster and a sql noob.  So please excuse me if I am displaying my ignorance with posting or sql.

First, does this look correct (I named all the columns as non-opaque as possible)?  I have to create reports that show the current inventory balance for all the products and for products individually as well as a ‘Transaction Register’ with running balance.

Second, provided the first answer is yes, is this a good candidate for creating a view?

Answer (score 0):

Complex question.  Difficult to answer without understanding the full scope of the project.  One point - I see there is no Current On-hand table.     I agree that the running balance at any point in time is best to use a calculated table.   It is however common practice to keep a current on-hand table.  This gives you the on hand inventory and values with-out having to sum up the transaction.  This is the approach in Microsoft Axapta, and other products I have worked with.